# Select and Copy multiple ranges with VBA

Tags: excel, range, vba

I want to copy multiple range to another workbook. I have the code below. How can I replace the number 1000 by iLastRow

```
iLastRow = Sh.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
sh.Range("A3:AG1000, AL3:EJ1000").Select
Selection.Copy
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the code below, explanation inside the code as comments:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyMultipleRanges()

Dim iLastRow As Long
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim MultiRng As Range

Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' <-- change to your sheet's name
With sh
    iLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    ' use the union to set a range combined from multiple ranges
    Set MultiRng = Union(.Range("A3:A" & iLastRow), .Range("AL3:EJ" & iLastRow))
End With

' copy the range, there's no need to select it first
MultiRng.Copy

End Sub
```

Another question is how you want to paste the merged reanges that have a gap in the middle.

Comment: The answer with method "Union" should be the right solution for this problem.

Comment: @DucAnhNguyen  in your post you mention range in he same sheet. It doesn't work on multiple ranges from different sheets.

Comment: @Shai Rado Your code 's not run.  I have to import from multiple excel file to one file with the existed field. May be I can copy in twice, but I want to try this way

Comment: @Luunguyen  read your post, you asked for 2 ranges in the same Worksheet, now you changed the scope entirely. It's hard to guess your needs if you post something , right ?

Comment: No. Still 2 ranges in the same worksheet. You can see my main code below

Comment: try move "End with" of "with sh" right after copy method ( before "with master") . Also normally, the dimension of copy and paste should be the same. I don't see any effort to select the same target dimension here. I think that what @ShaiRado mention "Another question is how you want to paste the merged reanges that have a gap in the middle."

Answer (score 3):

The Union method is a solution to this problem. but it also has its cons
[image: copy multirange test]

The union range should be the same first row and last row.
On the other hand, you can just select the first cell to paste.
you can alway do like this. the main point here is the row number should be the same. here I synchronize both range with the same variable. in your case, change to last cell.

```
j=1
i = 4
Set MultiRng = Union(Range("A" & j & ":B" & i), Range("D" & j & ":E" & i))
```

Comment: The problem is you replace the number of row `4` by `iLastRow`. If with specific number row, my code `sh.Range("A3:AG1000, AL3:EJ1000").Select` run, too

Answer (score 1):

Change Range params from this:

```
iLastRow = Sh.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
sh.Range("A3:AG1000, AL3:EJ1000").Select
```

To:

```
iLastRow = Sh.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
sh.Range("A3:AG" & iLastrow &", AL3:EJ" & iLastRow).Select
```

Since with multiple selection `Copy` will not work. You may need to call it twice in your case. (as per suggestion by @YowE3K)

```
sh.Range("A3:AG" & iLastrow).Select
Selection.Copy

sh.Range("AL3:EJ" & iLastrow).Select
Selection.Copy
```

Comment: @M Idrees @YowE3K You said that multiple selection Copy will not work but why this code run `sh.Range("A3:AG1000, AL3:EJ1000").Select`
`Selection.Copy`. I believe that we can find the way to select all

Comment: It can work on limited cases, like if you have consecutive rows selection used. If there are two different ranges on different locations on the sheet. It will give you error *That command cannot be used on multiple selections.*

Comment: No. `iLastrow` will be the limited cases

Answer (score 0):

```
 Option Explicit

    Sub import_APVP()

        Dim master As Worksheet, sh As Worksheet
        Dim wk As Workbook
        Dim strFolderPath As String
        Dim selectedFiles As Variant
        Dim iFileNum As Integer, iLastRowReport As Integer, iNumberOfRowsToPaste As Integer
        Dim strFileName As String
        Dim iCurrentLastRow As Integer, iRowStartToPaste As Integer
        Dim MultiRng As Range
        Dim startTime As Double

        getSpeed (True)
        Set master = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

        strFolderPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path

        ChDrive strFolderPath
        ChDir strFolderPath
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        'On Error GoTo NoFileSelected
        selectedFiles = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
                        filefilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*.xlsx*", MultiSelect:=True)
        For iFileNum = LBound(selectedFiles) To UBound(selectedFiles)
            strFileName = selectedFiles(iFileNum)

            Set wk = Workbooks.Open(strFileName)

            For Each sh In wk.Sheets
                If sh.Name Like "DATA*" Then
                    With sh
                        iLastRowReport = .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                        iNumberOfRowsToPaste = iLastRowReport + 2 - 1

                       '.Range("A3:AG" & iLastRowReport & " , AL3:EJ & iLastRowReport").Select
                       ' Selection.Copy
                        Set MultiRng = Union(.Range("A3:AG" & iLastRowReport), .Range("AL3:EJ" & iLastRowReport))
'you delete the 3 in range ("AL:EJ....) that make your code not work.
                        MultiRng.Copy
                        With master
                            iCurrentLastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                            iRowStartToPaste = iCurrentLastRow + 1

                            '.Activate ' <-- not needed
                              .Range("A" & iRowStartToPaste).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                             'ActiveSheet.Paste <-- not needed

                        End With

                    End With
                End If
            Next sh
            wk.Close
        Next
        getSpeed (False)

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    NoFileSelected:

    End Sub
```

Comment: You have not copied my code to yours, you have made some modifications which lead to this error. See how I found the `iLastRow`.

Comment: try move "End with" of "with sh" right after copy method ( before "with master") in YOUR code. Also normally, the dimension of copy and paste should be the same. I don't see any effort to select the same target dimension here. I think that what @ShaiRado mention "Another question is how you want to paste the merged reanges that have a gap in the middle."

Comment: @Shai Rado I copy your code, but my code use `iLastRowReport`, so I change `iLastRow` to `iLastRowReport`. It can't be lead to this error

Comment: It's useless you know. Because of error in `Set MultiRng = Union(.Range("A3:EF" & iLastRowReport), .Range("AL:EJ" & iLastRowReport))`

Comment: As mention in my post, you should have the same row for both range. In short, copy exactly @ShaiRado code which is "Set MultiRng = Union(.Range("A3:A" & iLastRow), .Range("AL3:EJ" & iLastRow))"

Comment: @ Duc Anh Nguyen, of course it's the same row for both range. Did you understand the problem?

Comment: A3:EF : from row 3 to last cell (1048576) ;  AL:EJ : from row 1 to last cell (1048576) so there is a different.

Comment: @Luunguyen. pls check that iLastRowReport gave an number >=3. smt like this " if iLastRowReport >3 then ..... else Debug.print "wrong" & iLastRowReport end if

Comment: @Duc Anh Nguyen It's always error in `MultiRng = Union(.Range("A3:AG" & iLastRowReport), .Range("AL3:EJ" & iLastRowReport))`

Comment: @Duc Anh Nguyen Thank you so much. My code have run.